# Font underlined in VUE routes with Bootstrap

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, bootstrap-vue

In my VUE project with Vuetify, I'm going to use the Bootstrap library.

It turns out that when I import the Bootstrap library, the text font and even the icon, the route has an underline. When I only worked with Vuetify, I didn't have this problem.

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

When I comment out the line in the project that imports the library, the underline disappears.

How can I solve this without having to put classes in every route in the project?

```
"vue": "2.6.14",
"bootstrap": "4.6.1",
"bootstrap-vue": "2.21.2",
"vuetify": "2.6.0",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my problem.
Bootstrap underlines link routes by default.
So I analyzed the file that is imported into the VUE project, and found several settings that underline links when the mouse pointer lands on them.

The file I analyzed is:

```
"bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";
```

So, I created a file where to put the CSS configs that I want to change BootstrapVue's default.

```
//bootstrapGlobal.css

a:not(.btn) {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I only needed to change this config, but if I need to change others I'll insert it in this global file.

This tip is for those who need it.

Happy ending!